# assign nothing as default open with application

Tags: finder, defaults, file-extensions

I usually have bunch of audio files (.mp3) with my music and some other non-audio files (.asd) in the same directory. To play some music quickly I just select all in Finder and hit <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> to open them in my default application (VLC). The .asd files will also get opened, but I don't ever want to open them. They are used by the Ableton Live application, but aren't meant to be opened with it.

Is it possible to assign "nothing" as a default application for .asd files? I'm thinking possibly using `defaults` or other some other command-line trick, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

[RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) - freeware, installs as a Control Panel. Yes, it's a million years old, yes it still works to Mojave, but may not at Catalina.

Extensions tab [might take a few seconds to populate], find your .asd in the list & set the default to `<disable>`

New kid on the block for when RC is no longer viable seems to be [SwiftDefaultApps](https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps) though it doesn't seem to be so simple for this task.